# Using disj to remove an element from a set in Clojure

Tags: clojure, set

Hi I've hit a brick wall whilst trying to remove an element from a set.

I have a map of cards.

```
   (def cards
  {
    :card1 {:name "Wisp"              :type "Monster"     :damage 1 :health 1 :cost 0 :charge "t"}
    :card2 {:name "Spider Tank"       :type "Monster"     :damage 3 :health 4 :cost 3}
    :card3 {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre" :type "Monster"     :damage 6 :health 7 :cost 6}

    }
 )
```

And a deck (set) of these cards.

```
(def deck1 (set (map cards '(:card1 :card2 :card3))))
```

When I use disj to try and remove one of these cards nothing happens.

```
(disj deck1 :card1)
```

I really have no idea why.

Comment: well, there is no element `:card1` in the `deck1` set. Probably what you want to do is `(disj deck1 (:card1 cards))`

Comment: `(clojure.pprint/pprint deck1)`

Answer (score 3):

leetwinski was right in the comments. `(disj deck1 (:card1 cards))` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid turning this into a set and simply use `dissoc` instead.  Dissoc works on a map rather than a set, so you can avoid the extra type conversion.

```
user=> (dissoc cards :card1)
{:card2 {:name "Spider Tank", :type "Monster", :damage 3, :health 4, :cost 3},
 :card3 {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre", :type "Monster", :damage 6, :health 7, :cost 6}}
```

Comment: this would remove the card from the set of available cards, rather then take this card out of the deck.

Comment: in the same idea, `(assoc-in cards [:card1 :available] false)`

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a typical clojure idiom:

```
'(:card1 :card2 :card3)
```

This is easier and cleaner:

```
[:card1 :card2 :card3]
```

Second, you are complicating your collections a bit, in my opinion. As stated in the other comments, you cannot `disj` a key that is not in there; your `map` function is returning the values associated with the keys `:card1` etc, so trying to disj the key on the results will do nothing.

Now, the fact you are turning this into a set only matters if you expect the values in your original map to possibly be duplicated in that map. Is it possible to have more than one Wisp card with the same damage, etc? If it is possible that :card5 and :card8, for example, could be identical values, then turning the map into a set will remove those duplicates. If it is not possible that cards would be identical, then the map already has unique keys that cannot be duplicated and so I'm not sure what you are gaining by transforming it into a set.

Answer (score 1):

`deck1` is

```
#{{:name "Wisp", :type "Monster", :damage 1, :health 1, :cost 0, :charge "t"}
  {:name "Spider Tank", :type "Monster", :damage 3, :health 4, :cost 3}
  {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre", :type "Monster", :damage 6, :health 7, :cost 6}}
```

This set does not contain the *value* `:card1`. So `(disj deck1 :card1)` has no effect.

You want something like

```
(apply disj deck1 (filter #(= (:name %) "Wisp") deck1))
```

... which removes all elements with `:name` `"Wisp"` - there is only one, giving

```
#{{:name "Spider Tank", :type "Monster", :damage 3, :health 4, :cost 3}
  {:name "Boulder Fist Ogre", :type "Monster", :damage 6, :health 7, :cost 6}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep a separate def `(def available-cards #{:card1 :card2 :card3})`.  Then you are not looking for a large object as the key.  If your cards change over time for some other reason you are not relying on a matching card object in the set.